# How to capture http GET and POST calls from windows application through Java

Tags: java, automation, fiddler, fiddlercore

I am working on automating windows installer based application and I have integrated AutoIt with java in order to capture the windows UI elements and processing.

Now I need to capture the POST(HTTP) calls and validate the request parameters.
Manually I can able to monitor and validate the POST calls through Fiddler.

I have browsed for any Fiddler API in order to integrate it with my java application and found that Fiddler provided Fiddlercore API which can be used only in C#.

Can anyone suggest that any alternative for fiddlercore api which can be used to monitor the network calls from windows applcation(.exe) through java?

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to do this with Fiddler or FiddlerCore; you can automate both and export the traffic they capture to files (e.g. .SAZ or .HAR) that you can then read using your Java program.

Comment: Hi Eric,
I would need to capture the http traffic at run time. 
Manually I will run the installer, accept/decline the offers, validate the POST requests in Fiddler(Inspectors->WebForms)

Need to automate the process.
Ran the installer -> Accept/Decline the offers(Automated using AutoIt+Java)
Validation of POST Http calls -> Kindly suggest how to use fiddlercore from java